# MySQL subquery in query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, relation

I have this database structure in my project.

nf_assembly_skills

```
part_id skill_id
    265        1
    265        2
```

nf_employee_skills

```
employee_id skill_id
          1        1
          3        2
```

nf_skills

```
id name
 1 Cutting
 2 Assembly
 3 Special Cutting
 4 Special Assembly
```

nf_assembly

```
 part_id part_number   part_description instruction                       lead_time ctime
       4 STR1019-ISS-3 HA-BSz1R,DMOSA/B &lt;span style=&quot;font-weig...      3600     0
```

I defined in nf_skills list of skills.
In nf_assembly list of documents.
In nf_assembly_skills i defined skills that required to access document.
In nf_employee_skills i defined employee skills.

What i want to do is run one query that return true or false  if employee have required skills.

I try to join run WHERE IN, also LEFT JOIN tables but nothing work. Anyway is this possible?

Comment: The screenshot doesn't include the structure for the table `nf_assembly`. Also, "run one query that return true or false if employee have required skills." *Do you mean, required skills to access a particular document?*

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny i updated screenshot with nf_assembly strucutre. Yes i want to get query that return access to single document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't super pretty.. But it will allow you to select all employees and whether or not they have access. It compares the counts of required skills for an assembly to the counts of skills an employee has for that assembly.

```
select pskills.part_id, epskills.employee_id,
case when epskills.num >= pskills.num then 'true' else 'false' end as [Access]
from (
    select part_id, count(distinct skill_id) as num
    from nf_assembly_skills
    --where part_id = 264
    group by part_id ) pskills  
inner join (
    select part_id, employee_id, count(distinct a.skill_id) as num
    from nf_assembly_skills a
    inner join nf_employee_skills e on a.skill_id = e.skill_id
    --where part_id = 264 and employee_id = 1
    group by part_id, employee_id) epskills 
on pskills.part_id = epskills.part_id
```

If you are just looking to do one employee and assembly at a time you can uncomment the two where clauses, though Nikoline's suggestion can achieve that and is much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, that exactly what im looking for!

Answer (score 1):

So the way I understand it, you want to make sure, the given employee has ALL of the skills required for that document.

I would probably solve it by creating a function that takes employee and document they want to access as input. There you could make a query that basically does a count of how many of the required skills the employee does NOT have.
Something like this:

```
select count(*)
from nf_assembly_skills a left join nf_employee_skills b on a.skill_id=b.skill_id
where a.part_id = [input part_id]
and b.employee_id = [input employee id]
and b.skill_id is null
```

If the count is > 0, you return false, else true.

Comment: Does it help? (If it does help, would you mind upvoting/accepting answer?)